# How to set String Value null in Android defined in HTML format?

Tags: android

I want to hide my String name when there is null data coming from JSON.. 
format is here

```
                String domain_head = "Domain :";
                String sub_head = "Sub-domain:";

                if(portfoliolist.get(position).getTagged_activity_first().equals("null")){
                    domain_head = "Nihal";
                }


                String myHtmlTxt = "<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0>"
                        + " <font color=#e25d2d>"
                        + data.get(position).getTime()
                        + ", </font> "
                        + " <font color=#0b4d73> "
                        + data.get(position).getCatname()
                        + " : "
                        + data.get(position).getType()
                        + " </font> "
                        + " <font color=#e25d2d>"
                        + data.get(position).getFieldvalue()
                        + data.get(position).getFieldname()
                        + " </br></font> "


                        + "<font color=#0b4d73><br>"+domain_head+" </font>"
                        + "<font color=#e25d2d> "
                        + data.get(position).getTagged_activity_first()
                        + "</font>"
                        + "<font color=#0b4d73><br>"+sub_head+"</font>"
                        + "<font color=#e25d2d>"
                        + data.get(position).getTagged_activity_second()
                        + "</font>" + "</body>";
```

here if domain_head is null then hide its sub_head data.. I tried but getting nullPOinterException.. please help me

Comment: Use an `if` statement.

Comment: yes I am using but still I ma failed :(

Comment: In the code you have shown here, there is no `if` statement which checks that `domain_head` is `null`. Please show us exactly what you tried and what happens when you try to running. Simply saying that you failed does not provide us with enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: Hello Sir @Code-Apprentice... I have a JSON link where from I am getting data and inflating data into textview.. Now I want to hide if any of them data is null.

Comment: try{
  
     String domain_title = "Domain:";
     if(data.get(position).getTagged_activity_first().equals("null")){
      System.out.println(data.get(position).getTagged_activity_first());
      domain_title = "";
     }

Comment: What did you try? What exactly do you want to hide?

Comment: Please edit your original question so that you can format the code so it is more readable.

Comment: I am posting my full code . please look at and let me know

Comment: Please post enough code to illustrate the problem which you are asking about and no more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104204/discussion-between-kitkat-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: please join Chat SIr.. I am unable to edit my question.. formatting issue is coming

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the immutable `String`, you should try `StringWriter` or `StringBuffer`. Build up the "string" in pieces

```
strWriter.append("some string");
if (domain_head != null) {
    strWriter.append("more string");
    strWriter.append("even more");
}

return strWriter.toString();
```